# Link key vault generated certificate with service principal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault

I want to link a key vault generated certificate with a service principal automatically. The end goal is to have the key vault auto renew the certificate and link it to the app registration. Is this possible?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? Permissions on key vault are independant from the keys/secrets.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @JoyWang I generated a certificate inside of the key vault. I set it to renew before it expires. I ran Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret to get the certificate itself. I then tried to add the certificate to the app registration using New-AzureRmADAppCredential but I got New-AzureRmADAppCredential : Update to existing credential with KeyId XXXXXXXXXX is not
allowed.